# Want to execute jar in 1.6 when 1.7/1.8 is installed

Tags: java, jvm

Hi as per my project needs, I should run a jar file using java 1.6 only.
But I installed 1.7 and 1.8 in my machine, may I know is there any way that I can do using command prompt and except installing 1.6. Please help me, All suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: even by command line you can change the java version globally also. So, that you can run the Jar on our required version.

Comment: @Pavan I am searching for that only, can you please help me with that. **Note: Without installation of Jre1.6, I would like to run my jar in that env using Jre 1.7 installation.**

Comment: firstly we need to install the required java version.run the following command in the terminal `update-alternatives --config java` It will prompt you the options.select the required version and run it.

Comment: I am unable to run the command `update-alternatives --config java`. Can you please help me with this... FYI, I am using windows7 OS.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about windows OS, I use **ubuntu**. whenever I issue this command it displays all the versions installed on our system. so, that we can switch over between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your operating system type and version.

However the most straightforward way won't change much, so I will mention it (until you supply more info, then I would be able to edit the answer accordingly).

Basically just prefix the jar file call with the path to your Java6 executable, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\java.exe <PATH TO YOUR JAR>
```

or

```
/usr/bin/java6 <PATH TO YOUR JAR>
```

**Edit**
As it appears from further comments - you'd like to run java program with JRE6 without one installed. IMHO it's impossible.

Important to note that Java7 is highly backwards compatible with Java6 and should run as expected in almost all cases, out of the box. [See Java7 compatibility page for details](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html). Therefore seems you'll be fine with just running the jar as you normally would.

**Edit2**
Additionally, if you run into those rare corner case incompatibility, consider to use [PortableApp java6 run-time](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable), which can be placed on your computer **without installing**

Comment: **I don't have jre6 in my machine.** I wanted to use jre7 only instead of again installing jre6. If you know any commands that I can execute my jar in jre6 env with jre7 installation let me know. Btw i am using Windows 7 OS.

Comment: IMHO there is no such way as Java7 is highly backwards compatible with Java6 and should run as expected in almost all cases, out of the box. See [Java7 compatibility page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) for details.

Therefore seems you'll be fine with just running the jar as you normally would.

Comment: Additionally, if you run into those rare corner case incompatibility, consider to use [PortableApp java6 run-time](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable), which can be placed on your computed without installing.

Comment: @Rakesh Please let me know if one comments worked for you so I could add them to answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, none of the comments are useful for me. I am trying to create Jre 1.6 environment with installation of Jre1.8 or Jre1.7. But not getting idea, so I installed Jre 1.8, Jre 1.7 and Jre 1.6 and switching between them depends on my requirement. :)

Comment: Of course, because it's the only way as stated in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and your effort Vano... :)

Answer (score 1):

In similar case I only choose in project properties which installed version I want to use. Version which first I download from website